# Set site is expired after submit form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have site with form with dropdown input. When you select some item from dropdown and submit form, you are redirected to another site with another form.

I need refresh first site if you press "Back" in your browser. Can I sent some header or something to say to browser, that site need to be reload? But only, when you submit form, no when you just visit first page.

Edit:\\ Sorry, I just realized, that form is sent to the same page, but in PHP, after saving data to DB, I use header() to redirect it to second page.

Edit2:\\

File **a.php**

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
  //save data do DB
  header("Location: b.php");
  exit();
}?>
<form method="post" action="a.php">
...
```

File **b.php**

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
  //save data do DB
}
//sending HTML with big form to user
```

When you submit form in a.php and everything is correct, you are redirected to b.php, but when you press back in b.php, you are returned to a.php and I need reload this page to update dropdown and rest of HTML

Comment: Set up a POST form on `a.php` that sends the user to `b.php`. And then `b.php` sends the user to the other site. Pressing the back button on the other site will trigger a warning in most browsers about resubmitting a POST form. Effectively, meaning your page will be re-downloaded.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized something, I edited main post, new text is after Edit:\\

Comment: You've lost me. You might want to re-word things here. Perhaps provide an example (use names for your pages and possibly sample code).

Comment: OK, second edit with examples

Comment: Yes, from `b.php` you are returned by Back button to `a.php`, and `a.php` have to be reloaded, not loaded from browser cache

Comment: Don't you really just need a header cache directive so the browser doesn't use the cached `a.php`?

Comment: Thanks, now it works better, but is there any chance to cahce site, and before `header("Location...")` change it to no cache? I just made `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
      header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() - 10));` before redirect, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your question being worded poorly, i am assuming that you are opening a new tab in the browser for the new form. So when the form is submit you just run this.

```
header ( 'Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ;
```